# How do I generate a QR code with a picture in Perl?

Tags: perl, qr-code

I want to generate a QR code with a picture in the center of QR code.

Is this possible to generate QR code with a picture inside the QR code with Perl? I tried different libraries, but still can't find the solution.

Here is a clear example, how it should look, QR code contains logo (picture) in the center:

[image]

I tried different Perl modules, and there is no possibility to customize QR code.

Comment: just overwrite the logo over the generated qrcode - it reduces the error protection but if you use a high enough level it should be okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Image::Magick` and `Imager::QRCode` you can pretty easily do this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Imager::QRCode;
use Image::Magick;
use Carp qw(croak);

my $qrcode = Imager::QRCode->new(
    size          => 10,
    margin        => 0,
    version       => 1,
    level         => 'H',
    casesensitive => 1,
    lightcolor    => Imager::Color->new( 255, 255, 255 ),
    darkcolor     => Imager::Color->new( 0,   0,   0 )
);

my $qrcode_img = $qrcode->plot('foo bar baz');

$qrcode_img->write( file => 'qrcode.gif' )
  or croak q{Failed to write QRCode: } . $qrcode_img->errstr;

my $magick_qrcode = Image::Magick->new;
$magick_qrcode->Read( filename => 'qrcode.gif' );

my $embedded_image = Image::Magick->new;
$embedded_image->Read( filename => 'embedded_image.png' );

$magick_qrcode->Composite(
    image => $embedded_image,
    qw(compose StcAtop gravity Center)
);

$magick_qrcode->Write( filename => 'final_qrcode.png' );
```

You can adjust the settings in the `Imager::QRCode` constructor to make the QRCode the colors and dimensions you're looking for as well.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for the idea, I’ll test it now, but the error-stability of the qr code remains a priority,

Comment: @Maksym You can adjust the fidelity and size of the QR code with the `Imager::QRCode` settings passed to the constructor to make it closer to what you want.

Comment: Re "*but the error-stability of the qr code remains a priority*", Overwriting part of the code with a logo will necessarily reduce "error-stability".